# What does struct.pack() do to network packets

Tags: python, struct, network-programming

The python official document mentions that 'struct' module is used to convert between Python and binary data structures.
What do binary data structures here refer to? As I understand, does the data structure refer to the packet structure as defined in network related C functions?

Does struct.pack(fmt,v1,v2) build a C equivalent structure of the fields v1,v2 in format fmt?? For example if I am building an Ip packet, my fmt is the IP header and values are ip header feilds?
I am referring to [this example](http://www.binarytides.com/raw-socket-programming-in-python-linux/) while understanding how network packets can be built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary data structures refers to the layout of the data in memory. Python's objects are far more complicated than a simple C `struct`. There is a significant amount of header data in Python objects that makes completing common tasks simpler for the Python interpreter.

Your interpretation is largely correct. The other important thing to note is that we specify a particular byte order, which may or may not be the same byte order used by a standard C structure (it depends on your machine architecture).

Comment: Thank You. Yes, I did understand the rationale behind byte order.